# Can not log Out from the application

Tags: shiro

My cookies had been protected by third party tool like “EditThisCookie”  [ chrome browser]  .when I try to log out using following code : [Use shiro for log out.]

```
            Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
            currentUser.logout();
            Executions.sendRedirect(“Login Page”);
```

It does not log out the application since on Second time when I enter the url it redirecting me to the home page. How can I Solve this problem.

Comment: And does it work when you disable the third party tool?

Comment: yes it works.when i unprotected[set as readonly cookie].

Comment: So do I understand correctly that your third party tool prevents the jsessionid cookie from being deleted?

Comment: yeah, third party tool doesnot allow to delete the jsessionid and rememberMe cookie.when the cookies is in protected mode.

Comment: The strange this is that although the cookie is still available, it should have been invalidated on the server. The logout method eventually calls httpSession.invalidate(). The implementation of invalidation is done by the container. What webcontainer do you use? Tomcat/jetty, something else?

Comment: I am using Tomcat  as webcontainer

Comment: What you can do and try and run your app on Jetty, see if that changes the behaviour.